# R - Polygon/Mapping Coding Query Error in measure_with_ruler(b, rulers[i] * 1000) : Ruler is longer than maximum distance found

Tags: r

Ran this code to determine the fractal dimesion/coastline (border) paradox of Switzerland but returned with following error: Error in measure_with_ruler(b, rulers[i] * 1000) :
Ruler is longer than maximum distance found

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
w <- world(path=".", resolution = 3)
switz <- w[w$GID_0=="CHE",]
plot(switz)
as.data.frame(switz)
prj <- "epsg:4149"
gswitz <- project(switz, prj)
dswitz <- disagg(gswitz)
head(dswitz)
a <- expanse(dswitz)
i <- which.max(a)
a[i] / 1000000
b <- dswitz[i,]
par(mai=rep(0,4))
plot(b)

measure_with_ruler <- function(pols, stick_length, lonlat=FALSE) {
    stopifnot(inherits(pols, "SpatVector"))
    stopifnot(length(pols) == 1)
    g <- geom(pols)[, c('x', 'y')]
    nr <- nrow(g)
    pts <- 1
    newpt <- 1
    while(TRUE) {
        p <- newpt
        j <- p:(p+nr-1)
        j[j > nr] <- j[j > nr] - nr
        gg <- g[j,]
        pd <- distance(gg[1,,drop=FALSE], gg, lonlat)
        pd <- as.vector(pd)
        i <- which(pd > stick_length)[1]
        if(is.na(i)) {
            stop('Ruler is longer than maximum distance found')
        }
        newpt <- i + p
        if(newpt >= nr) {
        break
        }
        pts <- c (pts, newpt)
    }
    pts <- c(pts, 1)
    g[pts,]
}

y <- list()
rulers <- c(25,50,100,150,200,250)
for (i in 1:length(rulers)) {
    y[[i]] <- measure_with_ruler(b, rulers[i]*1000)
}

par(mfrow=c(2,3), mai=rep(0,4))
for(i in 1:length(y)) {
    plot(b, col='lightgray', lwd=2)
    p <- y[[i]]
    lines(p, col='red', lwd=3)
    points(p, pch=20, col='blue', cex=2)
    bar <- rbind(cbind(525000, 900000), cbind(525000, 900000-rules[i]*1000))
    lines(bar, lwd=2)
    points(bar, pch=20, cex=1.5)
    text(525000, mean(bar[,2]), paste(rulers[i], ' km'), cex=1.5)
    text(525000, bar[2,2]-50000, paste0('(', nrow(p),')'), cex=1.25)
}
```

I edited the code for the country of Kazakhstan and it seemed to work fine

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
w <- world(path=".", resolution = 3)
kaz <- w[w$GID_0=="KAZ",]
plot(kaz)
as.data.frame(kaz)
prj <- "epsg:2939"
gkaz <- project(kaz, prj)
dkaz <- disagg(gkaz)
a <- expanse(dkaz)
i <- which.max(a)
a[i] / 1000000
b <- dkaz[i,]
par(mai=rep(0,4))
plot(b)




measure_with_ruler <- function(pols, stick_length, lonlat=FALSE) {
    stopifnot(inherits(pols, "SpatVector"))
    stopifnot(length(pols) == 1)
    g <- geom(pols)[, c('x', 'y')]
    nr <- nrow(g)
    pts <- 1
    newpt <- 1
    while(TRUE) {
        p <- newpt
        j <- p:(p+nr-1)
        j[j > nr] <- j[j > nr] - nr
        gg <- g[j,]
        pd <- distance(gg[1,,drop=FALSE], gg, lonlat)
        pd <- as.vector(pd)
        i <- which(pd > stick_length)[1]
        if(is.na(i)) {
            stop('Ruler is longer than maximum distance found')
        }
        newpt <- i + p
        if(newpt >= nr) {
        break
        }
        pts <- c (pts, newpt)
    }
    pts <- c(pts, 1)
    g[pts,]
}

y <- list()
rulers <- c(25,50,100,150,200,250)
for (i in 1:length(rulers)) {
    y[[i]] <- measure_with_ruler(b, rulers[i]*1000)
}

par(mfrow=c(2,3), mai=rep(0,4))
for(i in 1:length(y)) {
    plot(b, col='lightgray', lwd=2)
    p <- y[[i]]
    lines(p, col='red', lwd=3)
    points(p, pch=20, col='blue', cex=2)
    bar <- rbind(cbind(525000, 900000), cbind(525000, 900000-rulers[i]*1000))
    lines(bar, lwd=2)
    points(bar, pch=20, cex=1.5)
    text(525000, mean(bar[,2]), paste(rulers[i], ' km'), cex=1.5)
    text(525000, bar[2,2]-50000, paste0('(', nrow(p),')'), cex=1.25)
}
```

Are there any ideas on how I can fix the error?

[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6mrj.png)

Comment: I think, perhaps, a re-read of ?terra::expanse, viz  `For vector data, the best way to compute area is to use the
     longitude/latitude CRS. This is contrary to (erroneous) popular
     belief that suggest that you should use a planar coordinate
     reference system. This is done automatically, if ‘transform=TRUE’.`, as said, perhaps. And, measuring devices, outside the kubit, have generally accepted fractional measures.